# Angular $translate not working in one of my controllers

Tags: angularjs, translate, angular-translate

I'm using Pascal Prechts $translate in all of my controllers like this:

```
/* @ngInject */
function someController($filter) {      
    var vm = this;
    var translate = $filter("translate");
    vm.title = translate("LOGIN_TITLE");
}
```

However, it simply refuses to work in **only one** of them and I can't figure out why. The controller in question is not any different from the others and the console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: We will need more details, maybe a plunkr. Try to inspect what `translate` contains ? make sure the LOGIN_TITLE appears in your translation files

Comment: Did you properly [initialize the translation provider](https://angular-translate.github.io/)? Provide a running example.

Comment: I'm working on a plunkr.

Comment: Plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/cIFPKnKieKiYpkUzvZZI?p=preview
Both controllers seem to be broken here... however, in my application the userpasswordController manages to translate without a problem.

Comment: Note, I know it would be much better to stick with translating in the view, but I need to do it in the controller.